# How do I make listbox / listview like this

Tags: listview, vb6, listbox

If anyone can help each make listbox or listview be like the picture below?

Thank you
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIRUB.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRSWL.png)

Comment: You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: For VB6 you would need a 3rd party control or you would need to owner draw a listbox/listview control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0

> add ListView and ImageList

ImageList add one picture

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'init the view
ListView1.View = lvwSmallIcon
ListView1.View = lvwIcon

'init the listview
ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , "Filename", "Filename"

' pick one of two
ListView1.SmallIcons = ImageList1
ListView1.Icons = ImageList1

'set the value
Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(1, "aaa", "aaa", 1, 1)
Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(2, "bbb", "bbb", 1, 1)

End Sub
```

you can get [image]

Comment: Wow, thanks .
Thanks for your help :)